# how can i edit the value of add multiple dynamic form in react class?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on dynamic react form. I want to update dynamic form data. I have populate and get the data from  backend successfully but when I enter in input field for change some data then I'm not able to change it. I am adding here my form image. Please check and tell me how can I can fix it.

[image]

```
import React from "react"

const VarientDetailEdit = (props) => {

  return (
    props.varientDetails.map((val, idx) => {
      let sort=`sort-${idx}`, sku=`sku-${idx}`, waightunitno=`waightunitno-${idx}`, unit=`unit-${idx}`, mrp=`mrp-${idx}`, discount=`discount-${idx}`, price=`price-${idx}`, stock=`stock-${idx}`, minstock=`minstock-${idx}`, outofstock=`outofstock-${idx}`
      return (
        <div>
             <div style={{float:"right"}}>
             {
              idx ?
              <button  style={{paddingLeft:"10px"}} className="btn btn-danger" onClick={(() => props.delete(val))} ><i className="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> : null
              }
          </div> 
          <div><br></br><br></br>
            
          <div key={val.index} className='row'>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label>Sort:</label>
              <input type="text" value={val.sort} name="sort" data-id={idx} id={sort} className="form-control " />
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label>SKU</label>
              <input type="text" value={val.sku} name="sku"  data-id={idx} id={sku} className="form-control " />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label>Weight/Quantity</label>
              <input type="text" value={val.waightunitno} name="waightunitno" id={waightunitno} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div  className='row'>
             <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
               <label>Unit</label>
               <input type="text" value={val.unit} name="unit" id={unit} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label>MRP <em style={{color:"tomato"}}>*</em></label>
              <input type="text" value={val.mrp} name="mrp" id={mrp} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label>Discount(%) <em style={{color:"tomato"}}>*</em></label>
              <input type="text" value={val.discount} name="discount" id={discount} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div  className='row'>
             <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label>Price <em style={{color:"tomato"}}>*</em></label>
                <input type="text" value={val.price} name="price" id={price} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
             </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label>Stock  <em style={{color:"tomato"}}>*</em></label>
                  <input type="text" value={val.stock} name="stock" id={stock} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label>Min Stock Alert <em style={{color:"tomato"}}>*</em></label>
                  <input type="text" value={val.minstock}  name="minstock" id={minstock} data-id={idx} className="form-control " />
              </div>
              <div className='col-sm-4'>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="form-label">Variant Out of Stock Status <em style={{color:"tomato"}}>*</em></label>
                    <select name="outofstock" value={val.outofstock} id={outofstock} data-id={idx} className="form-control" >
                        <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                        <option value="In Progress">In progress</option>
                        <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                        <option value="Hold">Hold</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
             <hr className="my-4"></hr>
        </div>
          </div>
       
        </div>
      )
    })
  )
}
export default VarientDetailEdit
```

Parent component

```
handleChange = (e) => {

    if (["sort",  "sku", "waightunitno", "unit", "mrp", "discount", "price", "stock", "minstock", "outofstock"].includes(e.target.name)) {
        let varientDetails = [...this.state.varientDetails]
        varientDetails[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    } else if (["isTex"].includes(e.target.name)) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        console.log(e)
    // }else if (["files[]"].includes(e.target.name)) {
   
    //        this.setState({ files:e.target.files });
  
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
}

addNewRow = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        varientDetails: [...prevState.varientDetails, { index: Math.random(), sort:5,
            sku: "",
            waightunitno: "",
            unit:"",
            mrp:0,
            discount:0,
            price:0,
            stock:0,
            minstock:0,
            outofstock:""}],
    }));
}


deteteRow = (index) => {
    this.setState({
        varientDetails: this.state.varientDetails.filter((s, sindex) => index !== sindex),
    });
 
}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
  if(this.state.date==='' || this.state.description==='')
    {
        NotificationManager.error(" Error -Please Fill up  all Required Field!!!");
        return false;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<this.state.varientDetails.length;i++)
    {
            if(this.state.varientDetails[i].sort==='' || this.state.varientDetails[i].varient==='')
            {
                NotificationManager.error("Error- Product Varient Fields are required!!!");
                return false;
            }
    }

   const formData = new FormData();
   for (const file of this.state.files) {
        formData.append('file', file)
    }

     const config = {
        Headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
             "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x" +
                    "--AaB03x" +
                    "Content-Disposition: file" +
                    "Content-Type: png" +
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" +
                    "...data... " +
                    "--AaB03x--",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "type": "formData"
       }, 
        productId:this.state.id,
        name:this.state.name,
        description:this.state.description,
        lableType:this.state.lableType,
        photo:this.state.thumbNailphoto,
        isTex:this.state.isTex,
        GSTrate:this.state.GSTrate,
        GSTtyp:this.state.GSTtyp,
        HSNcode:this.state.HSNcode,
        videoUpload:this.state.videoUpload,
        // categoryId:this.state.categoryId,
        // subCategoryId:this.state.subCategoryId,
        tags:this.state.tags,
        
        file:formData,
        reccomendedProduct:this.state.reccomendedProduct,
        varientDetails:this.state.varientDetails
     
       
        
    };
    console.log(this.state)
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You want to Add New Product",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
        .then(async (success) => {
            if (success) {
                let list = await GetProductDetails.getUpdateProduct(config);
            
                if (list) {
                    this.setState({ isLoaded: false })
                    this.props.history.push("/admin/mainproduct/list")
                } else {
                    NotificationManager.error("Please! Check input field", "Input Field");
                }
            }
        });
}
clickOnDelete(record) {
    this.setState({
        varientDetails: this.state.varientDetails.filter(r => r !== record)
    });
}
render() {
    let { varientDetails,subCategoryId,files,updateFile,loading,productphotos,categoryId,reccomendedProduct } = this.state//let { notes, date, description, varientDetails } = this.state
console.log(updateFile)
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-9 col-lg-6">
                    <h2 className="mt-30 page-title">Products</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-3 col-lg-6 back-btn">
                    <button className='btntop btn text-light' onClick={(e) => this.handleBack()}><i className="fas fa-arrow-left" />cancle</button>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className='btntop btn text-light mx-2'>Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ol className="breadcrumb mb-30">
                <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/admin/mainproduct/list">Products</a></li>
                <li className="breadcrumb-item active">Edit Product</li>
            </ol>
            <hr></hr>

            <div className='container'>
                <form  onChange={this.handleChange} >
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-sm-8'>
                            <div className='row'>
                                <div className='col-sm-8'>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="name" class="form-label">Title <em style={{ color: "tomato" }}>*</em></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="name" value={this.state.name} name="name" class=" w3-input w3-border form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label className="form-label">Description*</label>
                                        <RichTextEditor
                                            style={{ height: " 275.438px" }}
                                            className="w3-input w3-border"
                                            content={this.state.description}
                                            handleContentChange={this.handleContentChange}
                                            placeholder="insert text here..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div className='col-sm-8 py-4'>
                                    <div className="form-group row">
                                       <label className="my-2">Lables</label>
                                       <label className="btn opt mx-2 col-2 active"style={{backgroundColor: "blue",borderColor: "#449D44"}}>
                                          <input type="radio" id="lableType" hidden name="lableType" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"/> None
                                      </label>
                                      <label className="btn opt col-2 mx-2"style={{backgroundColor: "#449D44",borderColor: "#449D44"}}>
                                          <input type="radio"  hidden id="lableType" name="lableType" value="veg" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"/> veg
                                      </label>
                                      <label className="btn opt mx-2 col-3" style={{backgroundColor: "#C9302C",borderColor: "#C9302C"}}>
                                           <input type="radio" hidden id="lableType" name="lableType" value="None Veg" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"/> None Veg
                                       </label>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='col-sm-12'>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword5" class="form-label">Tags</label>
                                        {/* <input type="text" id="inputPassword5" class="w3-input w3-border form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock"/> */}
                                        <TagsEditor setStateOfTags={this.setStateOfTags}  />
                                    </div>
                                </div><br></br>
                                <div className='col py-4'>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="isTex"value={this.state.isTex} id="isTex" data-toggle="switchbutton" checked data-onlabel="true" data-offlabel="false" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label htmlFor="isTex" class="form-label">is Taxt Enable</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className='row'>
                                    <div className='col-sm-4'>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-label">GST Rate<em style={{ color: "tomato" }}>*</em></label>
                                            <input type="number" value={this.state.GSTrate}  className=" w3-input w3-border form-control" name="GSTrate" id="GSTrate" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='col-sm-4'>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-label">GST Rate Type <em style={{ color: "tomato" }}>*</em></label>
                                            <select id="GSTtyp" value={this.state.GSTtyp} name="GSTtyp" className=" w3-input w3-border form-control">
                                                <option value={1}>Inclusive</option>
                                                <option value={0}>Exclusive</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='col-sm-4 py-2'>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="HSNcode" class="form-label">HSN Code</label>
                                        <input type="text" value={this.state.HSNcode} name="HSNcode" className='w3-input w3-border form-control' id="HSNcode" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" />
                                    </div>
                                </div><br></br>
                            </div>
                            {/* now we are using  varient dynamic form */}
                            <div className='varientheader py-4' style={{ paddingBottom: "15px" }}>
                                <a onClick={this.addNewRow} className="btn" style={{ float: 'right', color: "Tomato" }}><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Add More</a>
                                <h3 style={{ float: 'left', }}>Varients</h3>
                            </div>
                            <hr style={{ padding: "2px", border: "2 px solid black" }}></hr>
                            <div className="container py-4" style={{ border: "lightgray" }}>
                                <VarientDetailEdit add={this.addNewRow} delete={this.clickOnDelete.bind(this)} varientDetails={varientDetails} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='recomended product'>
                                <hr></hr>
                                <h3>Recommended Products</h3>
                                <hr></hr>
                                <div className='ex1'>
                                    <ReccomendedFormList  rowRcData={reccomendedProduct} setStaterecomended={this.setStaterecomended} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/* right section cotegory */}
                        <div className='col-sm-4'>
                            <div>
                                <h3>Category <em style={{ color: "tomato" }}>*</em></h3>
                                <div className='mx-4 my-2'>
                                    <div className='categorycontainer'>
                                     
                                        <CategoryListEdit data={categoryId} sdata={subCategoryId} setStateOfCategory={this.setStateOfCategory} />
                                        <hr></hr>
                                    </div>
                                    {/* file upload */}
                                    <div className='imagecontainer'>
                                        <h3>Upload Images</h3>
                                        <hr />
                                      
                                        <div className="wrapper">
                                            
                                            <div className="drop">
                                                 <div className="cont">
                                                    <i className="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                                                    <div className="tit">
                                                        Drag & Drop
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="desc">
                                                        your files to Assets, or
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <div className="browse">
                                                         
                                                          click here to browse
                                                      
                                                    </div>
                                                </div> 
                                               <input id="files"  multiple name="files[]" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} type="file" />
                                            </div>
                                             <ToastContainer autoClose={1500} />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        {this.state.filselected ? <div><i>{this.state.filselected}</i>
                                         {/* <div className="form-group">
                                            <button className="save-btn hover-btn" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmitPhoto} disabled={loading}>
                                                {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" />}
                                                {loading && <span>Upload</span>}
                                                {!loading && <span>Upload</span>}
                                            </button>
                                            <ToastContainer autoClose={1500} />
                                        </div> */}
                                        </div>:
                                        <p>Drag & Drop files here or click to browse.
                                            Note: Max 4 images are allowed.</p>
                                            }
                                        <div style={{display:"flex",margin:"10px"}} >
                                                { productphotos.map((item,i)=>(
                                                     <div className="img_wrp mx-2">
                                                    <img  width="60px" height="55px" value ={item.imgUrl} src={item.imgUrl} alt="video not found "/><i  onClick={(e) =>this.handlawsDeleteById(item.id,item.imgUrl)} className="fa fa-close close"></i>
                                                </div>

                                                ))}
                                        </div>
                                         <hr></hr>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='uploadfile'>
                                        <h3>Upload Video </h3>
                                        <input type="file" className="form-control" onChange={this.VideoUploadFile} />
                                        <p style={{ color: "blue",fontStyle:"italic",fontWeight:"bold" }}>{this.state.msgvideoUpload}</p>
                                         <div className="img_wrp">
                                            <img   width="200px" height="150px" src={this.state.videoUpload} alt="video not found "/><i  onClick={this.deletePhotoStaticVideo} className="fa fa-close close"></i>
                                        </div>
              
                                        {/* { this.state.uploadPercentage > 0 && <ProgressBar variant="danger" now={this.state.uploadPercentage} active label={`${this.state.uploadPercentage}%`} /> }<br></br> */}
                                        <div className='upload thambnail my-4'>
                                            <h3>Video Thumbnail Image</h3>
                                            <div className="file-area">
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <input type="file" className="form-control" onChange={this.ThumbnainVideoUpload} />
                                                    <div className="file-dummy">
                                                    
                                                        <i className="fas fa-plus mx-4 my-4"></i><br></br>
                                                        <span className="default">Click to select a file, or drag it here</span>
                                                        <span className="success">Great, your file is selected</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                   
                                                    <p style={{ color: "blue",fontStyle:"italic",fontWeight:"bold" }}>{this.state.msgThumb}</p>
                                                     <div className="img_wrp">
                                                        <img   width="200px" height="150px" src={this.state.thumbNailphoto} alt="thumbnail not found"/><i className="fa fa-close close" onClick={this.deletePhotoStaticThumb} ></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    {/* {(() => {
                                                        if (!this.state.photo)
                                                            return <button onClick={this.handleCanclePhoto}>delete</button>
                                                    }
                                                    )} */}
                                                    {/* { this.state.uploadPercentage > 0 && <ProgressBar variant="danger" now={this.state.uploadPercentage} active label={`${this.state.uploadPercentage}%`} /> }<br></br> */}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: These inputs appear to be controlled inputs and there are not any `onChange` handlers to manage updating them anywhere.

Comment: @Ashutosh kumar, you need to make a function in parent control and needs to pass the value to that function. In this component, you are just rendering data, not updating data.

Comment: ihave all ready writen there onChange  function

Comment: handleChange = (e) => {

        if (["sort",  "sku", "waightunitno", "unit", "mrp", "discount", "price", "stock", "minstock", "outofstock"].includes(e.target.name)) {
            let varientDetails = [...this.state.varientDetails]
            varientDetails[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        } else if (["isTex"].includes(e.target.name)) {
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
       }
        else {
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. We have to use `defaultValue` to solve this problem.

```js
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.value || ''} />
```